# Iphone: LA.com app style menu

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I need to make an app very similar to the LA.Com iphone app. Specifically, I need the sliding top menu with sub menus. I wanted to know if this is already made by someone and is available for download? I couldn't find anything yet.

http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/la-com/id403739318?mt=8

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a custom slideview, as you see they've got two slide views the biggest one that "spawns" the items on the smallest one, the dark gradient effect is easily reproducible by overlaying an image, they also change the "selected tab" appearance, using the white one with the arrow pointing to bottom.

This UI is reproducible in UIKit, but they might have used a tool like titanium or so on. . .

Personally I don't like that interface, a tab bar is standard but is more useful: spinning a wheel on the top of the screen is not comfortable, and also you can't have all the elements in sight to reach them with a glance...obviously this is personal, if you need it you need it ^^!

Comment: thanks, just wanted to know if there was a ready-made template or something available since a lot of other apps seem to be using this type of menu.. and yeah I do need this, this is how the clients want it.